How to get information of policies from Apache Ranger in java source code?
I am implementing a tool that can get data of policies from Apache Ranger.
My service in Apache Ranger has three policy types: Access, Masking, and Row Level Filter.
Are there any Apache Ranger APIs that can return information of policy?
I found in RangerBasePlugin class, that there are three functions:

isAccessAllowed for Access policy type
evalDataMaskPolicies for Masking policy type
evalRowFilterPolicies for Row Level Filter type

They return data as my expectation but I do not understand these functions.
I do not know if using them is correct or not.
